# Can $(R,.,+)$ forms a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition, examples-counterexamples

From the definition of a ring we know that $~(R,+,.)~$ is ring if $~(R,+)~$ is an abelian group and $~(R,.)~$ is a semi-group, that is closed and associative and multiplication is distributive. Now my question, is there any ring exists of the form $~(R,.,+)~$?
That is, let $~R=\mathbb R-\{0\}.~~$ Then $R$ is not closed under addition. In this case $(R,.,+)$ cannot be a ring. So can there any example such that $(R,.,+)$ forms a ring? Where multiplication and addition has same definition.
For jist, can we define a ring $(R, \oplus, \odot)$ such that
$$a \oplus b =a.b ~~\text{and}~~~ a \odot b=a+b.$$

Comment: No, the multiplication isn't invertible because of $0$ and so it cannot be an addition operator

Comment: @MichaelBarz That sounds like an answer.

Comment: In any ring $0.a=0$ for all elements $a$, so if there is more than one element then multiplication by $0$ is not injective so multiplication cannot be a group operation.  Thus the only example is the trivial one element ring where $0=1$ and addition and multiplication are the same.  A closely related notion to what you are asking for is tropical geometry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry

Comment: Aso note that some authors require rings to be unital (have a multiplicative identit0)  But under this definition, yeah, only the trivial ring works due to the simple proof that if $0=1$ then everything equals $0$

Comment: @tkf can't I take $0$ as the unity element and $1$ as the zero element in this case? For that case, can there be any example of ring be possible?

Comment: Regardless of whether $0$ is regarded as a unity element or not, addition by it (or any other element) must be injective, in order to have a ring.  Thus you cannot have ring multiplication as your addition (except in the trivial case that I mentioned).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Consider the zero ring (the ring with exactly 1 element).

Note that any ring $(R, +, \cdot)$ such that $(R, \cdot, +)$ must be the zero ring, since $0$ would have to be a unit. Whenever $0$ is a unit, we have $0 \cdot a = 1$ for some $a$. But $0 \cdot a = 0$, and hence $0 = 1$, and hence the ring is the zero ring.